# Why is the API call not working in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, but the same API is working fine in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

One of my code is perfectly working in ASP.NET MVC 5, but when I am using almost same logic to call the API from ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, then the API always returns an error.

Same parameters and same address is being used in both technologies but the old approach is working.

Please see my old and new Logic to call this API, and guide me how to fix it.

The API Url is :

```
https://pcls1.craftyclicks.co.uk/json/rapidaddress?key=mykey&amp;include_geocode=true&amp;&amp;postcode=DD68AB&response=data_formatted
```

ASP.NET MVC 5 - working fine:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string addressUri = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["addressUri"];
    var uri = addressUri + postcode.Replace(" ","") + "&response=data_formatted";

    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    string textResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    lObjApiRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressLookupViewModel>(textResult);
}
```

ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - results in error:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    string addressUri = Configuration["CustomSettings:AddressUri"];
    string uri = addressUri + postcode.Replace(" ", "") + "&response=data_formatted";

    string textResult = "";

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(uri),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                };

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        textResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                      
    }
}
```

The steps are simple to reproduce the case. Just create an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project and try my code.

Please guide me to resolve the issue in a better way.

Why I am always getting this error:

> { "error_code":"0001",
> "error_msg": "No data was found for the requested postcode." }

Comment: What values are you using in your example? The error seems pretty clear - no data found for that postcode ..... are you **SURE** there is data for the post code you used in your sample calls=?

Comment: This key=mykey  parameter needs to filled by authorized users. If you 'll see in the API Url.   If I added the authorized key then it is 100% working in my Asp.net mvc 5 code. Yes it is return the even If i paste the url in the browser then it gets the data

Comment: What does your controller action look like that's handling these?  Are you sure its getting in there?

Comment: thank you all. Issue has been resolved now.  The issue is in the url.  correct url doesn't include amp; symbol  https://pcls1.craftyclicks.co.uk/json/rapidaddress?key=mykey&include_geocode=true&postcode=DD68AB&response=data_formatted